# How to mock callback function used in hook which is bound with useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks

I'm trying to mock callback function(cb) and want to check whether called 1 times.

and I've tried:

```
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    const cb = (t: number) => `message-${t}`
    const spy = jest.fn(cb)
    // This one also fails.
    // jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValue({ current: cb });
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useTimer(3, cb))

    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current[0]).toBe(3))
    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current[1]).toBe('message-3'))
    await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)) // received 0
```

```
const useTimer = (
  startTimeSec: number,
  cb: (currentSeconds: number) => string = (c) => '',
): [number, string] => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(startTimeSec)
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState<null | number>(null)
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('')
  const callback = React.useRef(cb)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTimeSec) {
      setTimer(startTimeSec)
      setMessage(callback.current(timer))
    }
  }, [startTimeSec])

  //...

  return [timer, message]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the mocked callback function `spy` to `useTimers` rather than the `cb`.

Besides, let's recall the conception of `useRef()`:

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue).

This means your mocked `cb` function will be the value of the `.current` property.

E.g.

`userTimer.ts`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useTimer = (startTimeSec: number, cb: (currentSeconds: number) => string = (c) => ''): [number, string] => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(startTimeSec);
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState<null | number>(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const callback = React.useRef(cb);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTimeSec) {
      setTimer(startTimeSec);
      setMessage(callback.current(timer));
    }
  }, [startTimeSec]);

  return [timer, message];
};

export { useTimer };
```

`useTimer.test.ts`:

```
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useTimer } from './useTimer';

describe('useTimer', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const cb = (t: number) => `message-${t}`;
    const spy = jest.fn(cb);
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useTimer(3, spy));

    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current[0]).toBe(3));
    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current[1]).toBe('message-3'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66452119/useTimer.test.ts
  useTimer
    ✓ should pass (20 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   92.31 |    33.33 |   66.67 |     100 |                   
 useTimer.ts |   92.31 |    33.33 |   66.67 |     100 | 3-10              
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.931 s
```